# Updating global js variable within function and sending updated to HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

I am having a really hard time updating a global variable and sending the updated to HTML.

I have the following in HTML:

```
We found <script type="text/javascript">
var $mainCount; 
document.write($mainCount); </script> places for you!
```

In Javascript:

```
   var $mainCount = 3; //Global variable

   if (1 = 1) {
   test();
   }

   function test() {
   $mainCount;

   for (var p = 0; p < 10; p++){

   $mainCount = p;
}
}
```

However, the HTML page does not update the number to 9, and still writes 3 as the global variable was declared as first

Comment: What are you expecting `$mainCount;` to do? Also, don't use `document.write`

Comment: did you called `test()` method, and you have remove `a` from for loop

Comment: This above is just used as an example of what i want to achieve, the code is much longer than this. I am expecting $mainCount to update as a variable, and then the HTML document to display the updated variable. However, the updated variable will not be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we stated in comments you will have to use javascript for it.

```
var $globalVariable = 3;

(function() {
  console.log('asa');
  $globalVariable = 9;
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = $globalVariable;
})();
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Cdv3/) code.

Comment: Very awesome! This works exactly as intended :) Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to bind HTML to a JavaScript variable.

If you want to update the HTML, then you need to use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) to do it.

Comment: So there is no way to show a simple integer value within an html docoument, and update the variable by Javascript?

Comment: no, either you need a data binding, or you need just to update your dom. All this is acheved only with javascript, at least.

Comment: I would like not to have tons of if else statements in the js and html document. I am making the js count up to 300 different places, but this amount will update if the user sorts in the places. 

I simply need the HTML document to write the counted amount on the screen. I can fetch the data from the Javascript, but i guess this is only done to global variables when the page is loaded. Isn't there a way to force an update of a global variable and re-load this to the html document?

Comment: @Quest — Data binding is still JS, it's just that you have a big bunch of generic JS library supporting you.

Comment: Its not that i have to literaly update the HTML, as i only have to update the script in the HTML document. I don't know if that is the same as what you are describing, it might be thou

Comment: @Quentin yes, that is what I said that anyway you need a JS for it.